# Use of 'random_state' parameter in sklearn.utils.shuffle?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, shuffle

what is the random_state parameter in `shuffle` in `sklearn.utils`? any one can explain random_state with some sample?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The `shuffle` is used to shuffle your matrices randomly. Programmatically, random sequences are generated using a seed number. You are guaranteed to have the same random sequence if you use the same seed. The `random_state` parameter allows you to provide this random seed to sklearn methods. This is useful because it allows you to reproduce the randomness for your development and testing purposes. So, in the `shuffle` method, if I use the same `random_state` with the same dataset, then I am always guaranteed to have the same shuffle. Consider the following example:

```
X = np.array([[1., 0.], [2., 1.], [0., 0.]])
X = shuffle(X, random_state=20)
```

If this gives me the following output,

```
array([[ 0.,  0.],
      [ 2.,  1.],
      [ 1.,  0.]])
```

Now, I am always guaranteed that if I use the `random_state = 20`, I will always get exactly the same shuffling. This si particularly useful for unit tests, where you would like to have reproducible results for asserting your conditions being tested.

Hope that helps!

Answer (score 2):

Besides the cases that @Abhinav gave, the random_state can be useful in this situation:
Imagine you have 2 nparrays/dataframes..., and you need to shuffle their rows the same way (For example, the first row in both arrays will be the 20th, the 2nd will be the 5th...)

You can do it by keeping the same random_state in both statements:

```
array1_shuffled = sklearn.utils.shuffle(array1, random_state=42)
array2_shuffled = sklearn.utils.shuffle(array2, random_state=42)
```

Comment: You actually don't need to use a random state to shuffle two lists the same way, you can simply do:
`array1_shuffled, array2_shuffled = sklearn.utils.shuffle(array1, array2)`